# Smart_Selects en Django 3.0.2

Tags: python, django, django-smart-selects

soy nuevo en Django y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de crear smart_selects en django 3.0.2? tengo entendido que el paquete funciona en las versiones anteriores de django, pero existe alguna forma de usar algo parecido en la parte de administracion de django 3.0.2? De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si consulta la documentación, explica cómo implementarlo en Django admin:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedManyToManyField

class Publication(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Writer(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   publications = models.ManyToManyField('Publication', blank=True, null=True)

class Book(models.Model):
   publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication)
   writer = ChainedManyToManyField(
       Writer,
       horizontal=True,
       verbose_name='writer',
       chained_field="publication",
       chained_model_field="publications")
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

[Documentación de django-smart-selects](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects#using-chained-fields-in-the-admin)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero creo que este modulo de django-smart-selects ya no esta disponible para django 3.0.2 ya que he intentado y me manda errores

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar los errores?

Comment: claro me dice lo siguiente:

Comment: File "E:\Users\elver\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\django-smart-selects\smart_selects\db_fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\elver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)

Comment: Ese error no tiene nada que ver con django-smart-selects. Revisa esta solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193514/importerror-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils

Comment: El problema es que django 3.0 ya manda ese error, la solucion que dan es hacer un downgrade a django 2.4

Comment: Logre quitar ese error pero ahora aparece este

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: chainedfk is not defined ReferenceError: chainedfk is not defined

Comment: Usa <script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script> en el template https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338665/django-smart-selects-doesnt-work-in-templates/35772760